# How to put borders closer to the text and image and make background gray in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is what I've done:

```css
body {
  background-color: #d92626;
  color: white;
}
body {
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  padding: 50px 50px;
}
.test {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">
        My text
    </h1>
  <h2 align="center">
        MORE MORE MORE<br><br><br>
    </h2>
  <img class="test" src="http://www.velior.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Test-Computer-Key-by-Stuart-Miles.jpg" height="300" width="300">
</div>
```

How can I now move left and right border closer to the text and image, and then make the background between left and right border gray?

Comment: You should really get yourself some basic css tutorials, this is basic stuff

Comment: @Aides I finished a course on CodeAcademy and did a few projects on Dash, but didn't learn about this. If it is basic, you probably now the answer... ?

Comment: In web HTML is for structure and CSS for design. When you do `body { //stuff }` you change the style of your body (whole window basically), not the border of your text and images. As lots of people have stated in the answers you can wrap your elements in a `div` (as you already did) - a `div` is basically an empty container - and then style that container with CSS. Always remember, you directly apply CSS to some HTML elements!

Comment: And to all those people answering this question, if you answer a question for a beginner like this please only post complete, correct and correctly formatted code!

Comment: @Aides, Instead of starting needless discussion and patronizing people, it would be more constructive to "just help people and explain things" politely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borders are placed around an element's dimensions, in your case, the `body` tag covers the entire window. If you wanted them to be *closer* you can add borders to another element than body, and make it with less width.

I see you already have a container (`.container`) so you can use it and apply the borders and background to it while adding for example `width: 60%` and then `margin: 0 auto` to center it horizontally.

```css
body {
  background-color: #d92626;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  width:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: gray;
}

.test {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">
    My text
  </h1>
  <h2 align="center">
    MORE MORE MORE<br><br><br>
  </h2>
  <img class="test" src="http://www.velior.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Test-Computer-Key-by-Stuart-Miles.jpg" height="300" width="300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your container div to achieve what you want:

```css
body {
    background-color: #d92626;
    color: white;
}


div.container {
    margin: 0 50px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    color: #000000;
}

.test {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">
    My text
  </h1>
  <h2 align="center">
    MORE MORE MORE<br><br><br>
  </h2>
  <img class="test" src="http://www.velior.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Test-Computer-Key-by-Stuart-Miles.jpg" height="300" width="300">
</div>
```

Comment: Took the code from the original before it was edited. Look before you shoot, please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `border` and `background` in the `.container` instead of the body.

DEMO:

```css
body {

  background-color: #d92626;

  color: white;

}

body {

  padding: 50px 50px;

}

.test {

  display: block;

  margin-left: auto;

  margin-right: auto;

}

.container{
  background:gray;

  border-left: 5px solid black;

  border-right: 5px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">
    My text
</h1>
  <h2 align="center">
    MORE MORE MORE<br><br><br>
</h2>
  <img class="test" src="http://www.velior.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Test-Computer-Key-by-Stuart-Miles.jpg" height="300" width="300">
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your content in a div and then apply border and red background to new div and grey background to `body`

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 align="center">
      My text
    </h1>
    <h2 align="center">
      MORE MORE MORE<br><br><br>
    </h2>
    <img class="test" src="http://www.velior.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Test-Computer-Key-by-Stuart-Miles.jpg" height="300" width="300">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  background: #d92626;
}

.test {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/parj6ep1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: #d92626;
  color: white;
}
.test1{
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  width:400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gray;
}
.test {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="test1">
  <h1 align="center">
        My text
    </h1>
  <h2 align="center">
        MORE MORE MORE<br><br><br>
    </h2>
  <img class="test" src="http://www.velior.ru/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Test-Computer-Key-by-Stuart-Miles.jpg" height="300" width="300">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```